# Layers of Abstraction: How far away from the intended Runtime Object?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I hope this is as clear as it is in my head.

I think I understand the essence of polymorphism. But a thought crossed my mind. Imagine I need a service from a class which is further down in hierarchy :

java.lang.Object

..

java...TheirClass implements ItheirClass

```
public class MyClass1 {
 private Object theirClass;

 public MyClass1(Object thierClass) {
    this.theirClass = (ItheirClass) theirClass;
 }
}
```

or

```
public class MyClass2 {
 private ItheirClass theirClass;

 public MyClass2(ItheirClass thierClass) {
    this.theirClass = theirClass
 }
}
```

Which is preferred and why? Would a 'instanceOf' checking of the passed object to the constructor be necessary in both or just the first implementation? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the need in the first case to cast `theirClass` to `ItheirClass` when you've declared it `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: If I recollect, I read somewhere that the typecasting is necessary to have access to methods in the runtime object. My thought is without the casting, a theirClassMethod() call, not inherited from Object class, will fail.

Comment: Sure, so in the first case you could cast `theirClass` to `Itheirclass` when you want to call `theirClassMethod()` which is specified in the interface. Or you declare `private ItheirClass theirClass` and when you assign the field in the constructor you cast it since the parameter is `Object theirClass`

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably stay clear of the former since it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is preferred.

If you make a mistake and feed each an argument of the wrong type, the latter will alert you at compile time, but the former will not fail until runtime.

A lesser issue is that typecasting is not a free operation in Java, so if this was in heavily used code, you have taken on a smallish runtime performance burden for no gain using the former.

Comment: Thanks Mel. Clears up some doubt.